# How to add a grey description bar under UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Like this one

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=284862083&mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

The grey bar with text "Most E-Mailed..." will always stay on top when the user scroll the content.

Can anyone give me an idea how to make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add an imageview with this image and set a label on it with what text you wanna display. I think this is what you want.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand, I am new to iOS development.  Can you give me more details?

Comment: See you just need add an imageview in your main view of the class below your navigation bar. And set the image of that imageview as the gray bar. Now add a label on the imageview like [imageview addSubview:label]. After this set the text of the label as ...(whatever you want). Now add a scrollview below this imageview on your main view and thats it your job is done.

Comment: Yeah, i got it done.  Thanks a lot.  I was not able to do so before just cause I used UITableViewController as the base class of the view below navigation.  Now I changed to UIViewController, added a label on the top and then add tableview below it.  All set.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog entry by someone who dissects how the NYTimes app was made: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/12/bars-like-the-new-york-times-app/

Comment: Nice article, but it didn't mention how to create the grey description bar.  Thanks a lot still.